# Invalid @belongsTo directive on currency. Partial sort keys are not accepted

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

Not sure how you achieve this in amplify grapgql

I have the advert model that has two fields toCurrency and fromCurrency that is link to currency model?

```
type Advert @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  currency: Currency @belongsTo(fields: ["fromCurrencyId", "toCurrencyId"])
  fromCurrencyId: ID!
  toCurrencyId: ID!
}

type Currency @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  code: String!
  symbol: String!
  Adverts: [Advert] @hasMany(fields: ["id"])
}
```

I get this error `Invalid @belongsTo directive on currency. Partial sort keys are not accepted.`when trying to push.